# Как осуществить Python socket соединение к ПК в частной сети

Tags: python, сеть, сокет

Пк к которому нужно подключиться ожидает TCP соединение по адресу: 192.168.1.25 : 40987

Данный пк находится в локальной сети роутера, а роутер в свою очередь находится в частной сети провайдера где у всех серые динамические адреса(172.43.56.65 допустим). В частных сетях все участники имеют ОДИН белый внешний адрес доступный из интернета. Значит подключение на прямую осуществить не получится, и как я полагаю нужно делать это так:

88.32.45.6(внешний, белый адрес) --> 172.43.56.65(динамический, серый адрес) --> 192.168.1.25(локальная сеть)

Вопрос, как осуществить данное подключение, если для прямого подключения к пк у которых сразу белый адрес требуется ввести только его. Всё это естественно на Python, библиотека socket

Comment: питон тут вообще не причем. надо пробрасывать порт сначала на том маршрутизаторе у которого белый ip, потом на втором маршрутизаторе. ну и менять динамический ip на статику, что бы это все работало

Comment: Внешний сервер нужен